# cannot be converted to JSONObject for java.lang.String

Tags: android, json

I read some about the error in google , i am bit new to php

```
org.json.JSONException: Value Record of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

This is my php

```
$sqlchk="SELECT STATUS FROM OBJECTS WHERE ID=$id";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sqlchk);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array('ID'=>$row[0],
'STATUS'=>$row[1]
));
}


echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
```

this is my code java

```
try {
    try {
        responses = client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String jsonData = responses.body().string();
    JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    JSONArray Jarray = Jobject.getJSONArray("result");

    if (!responses.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + responses);


    for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object     = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
        String    prize = object.getString("STATUS");
        System.out.println(prize);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
}
    catch (Exception e) {
   Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected io exception", e);
}
```

edit 1

```
$id= isset($_POST['id']) ? intval($_POST['id']) : null;
$likes= isset($_POST['likes']) ? intval($_POST['likes']) : null;


$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$uname,$pwd,$db) or die(mysqli_error());

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "UPDATE OBJECTS SET LIKES=$likes where ID=$id ";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

} 

$sqlchk="SELECT ID,STATUS FROM OBJECTS WHERE ID=$id";
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlchk);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array('ID'=>$row[0],
'STATUS'=>$row[1]
));
}


echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));



$conn->close();
```

Comment: You should post your JSON data

Comment: Why don't you debug your app, place a breakpoint on line `JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData)` and verify what your input string contains?  I suspect PHP displays some sort of warning or notice.

Comment: The problem is actually inside the `for` loop

Comment: `if (!responses.isSuccessful())` should be before you attempt anything with the response data

Comment: And if you are new to PHP, then why use it instead of a language you are familiar with that supports a web server and mysql libraries?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso I am getting the result from a query, there is an echo "success" in the php , is it because of it ?

Comment: @cricket_007 okay ill fix the responses condition i didnt notice that as for php i am learning it

Comment: If there is an `echo "success"`, then that isn't JSON, and Android will throw an error

Comment: @Moudiz please post the content of `jsonData`

Comment: when you access your php file, what does echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result)); give you?

Comment: @user1506104 how do i know that yet? from application i am having error , and from url i am getting it empty url

Comment: forget about the android app for now. fix the php script first. once you have the correct JSON by accessing your url thru your web browser, you can now check from your android app.

Comment: @user1506104 what i am doing from my php code I am remove all the warning messages : `Notice: Undefined index: id in /home/justdb/public_html/old-files/singleactivity.php on line 10
Notice: Undefined index: likes in /home/justdb/public_html/old-files/singleactivity.php on line 11
{"result":[]}` I write them like this but still error occures : 
$id=0;
$likes=0;
$id= intval($_POST['id']);
$likes= intval($_POST['likes']);

Comment: can you paste here your updated php file?

Comment: @user1506104 chk my edit

Comment: You can't check POST requests simply by accessing the URL in your browser. You need to use POSTMAN, for example, and set the request type to POST

Comment: @cricket_007 i will try postman howerver it was working before with no warning

Comment: replace $_POST with $_GET, then try accessing this: your.domain.com/old-files/singleactivity.php?id=1&likes=1 from your web browser

Comment: can't I keep using $_POST ?

Comment: once you fix this error, you can revert to POST

Comment: @user1506104 i fixed it there was several errors but the main one was because of isset , if you want add an answer `$id= isset($_POST['id']) ? intval($_POST['id']) : null;
$likes= isset($_POST['likes']) ? intval($_POST['likes']) : null;`

Comment: i didn't get you. it worked?

Comment: yes , add an answer so i can close this question if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the PHP code first and make sure that it gives you the right JSON string. To verify, try to manually access the php file with the proper POST headers (id and likes).